# PHP]ClassNotFoundException Can't access to a webpage

Tags: php, html, css, macos, symfony

I'm trying to access in a webpage but i can't and i dont understand why.

This is my problem :

> ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "ResourceBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Intl" in /Users/neqodev/Desktop/ap-cks-preprod/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/ResourceBundle/Reader/BinaryBundleReader.php line 37. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

And the file :

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle\Reader;

use Symfony\Component\Intl\Exception\ResourceBundleNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle\Util\ArrayAccessibleResourceBundle;


/**
 * Reads binary .res resource bundles.
 *
 * @author Bernhard Schussek <bschussek@gmail.com>
 *
 * @internal
 */
 class BinaryBundleReader implements BundleReaderInterface
 {
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function read($path, $locale)
{
    // Point for future extension: Modify this class so that it works also
    // if the \ResourceBundle class is not available.
    try {
        // Never enable fallback. We want to know if a bundle cannot be found
        $bundle = new \Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle($locale, $path, false);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // HHVM compatibility: constructor throws on invalid resource
        $bundle = null;
    }

    // The bundle is NULL if the path does not look like a resource bundle
    // (i.e. contain a bunch of *.res files)
    if (null === $bundle) {
        throw new ResourceBundleNotFoundException(sprintf(
            'The resource bundle "%s/%s.res" could not be found.',
            $path,
            $locale
        ));
    }

    // Other possible errors are U_USING_FALLBACK_WARNING and U_ZERO_ERROR,
    // which are OK for us.
    return new ArrayAccessibleResourceBundle($bundle);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getLocales($path)
{
    $locales = glob($path.'/*.res');

    // Remove file extension and sort
    array_walk($locales, function (&$locale) { $locale = basename($locale, '.res'); });
    sort($locales);

    return $locales;
 }
}
```

Comment: There's no such class `\Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle`. There's nothing to say more here. Why do you think there is such class?

Comment: In' a linux system it works , i dont know why :o

Comment: Which version of Symfony is it? Have you modified this file? I was able to find `BinaryBundleReader` only in version 2.4, but its content is different.

Comment: My Symphony version is 2.4

Comment: So you must have edited this file since it has a slightly different content in the source: https://github.com/symfony/intl/blob/2.4/ResourceBundle/Reader/BinaryBundleReader.php

Comment: i had copy/paste the files but i got the same results

Comment: I can see you're just messing things up. 3rd party code should be just fetched once into the project and stay untouched. I cannot guess how you came into this state of code therefore it's hard to help you. By the way, if you copied this content of this file to fix it, it's not possible to get the same result since there's no reference to `Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle`.